# Accidentally deleted the database without backup,can it still be recovered

Tags: sql-server

Sqlserver database is accidentally deleted but without backup.
Is it still be able to recover back the database?
Does sqlserver keeps the deleted database in "recycle bin" just in case we can restore back?

Comment: SQL Server told the OS to delete the files and walked away. There are many resources available for recovering deleted files (with varying rates of success), but SQL Server won't help you.

Comment: At this point a "File Recovery" tool is your only option.

Comment: Does that mean if you delete the database through the SQL server management studio ssms
The database file is still kept somewhere in the hard-disk which can be retrieved back.If so any idea where will the location be and what will be the filename be?